# Is there a option to clean this SQL query up

Tags: sql, select

I was wondering if it was possible to make this query smaller

```
SELECT Templates.TempName
      ,TimeSpans.TimeSpan
      ,TemplateSlotTypes.[Type]
      ,TemplateSlots.Potition
      ,TemplateSlots.duration
FROM TimeSpans
INNER JOIN Templates ON  Templates.TimeSpanId = TimeSpans.Id
INNER JOIN TemplateSlots ON  Templates.Id = TemplateSlots.TemplateId 
INNER JOIN TemplateSlotTypes ON  TemplateSlots.[Type] = TemplateSlotTypes.Id
```

Comment: Mysql and sql server are completely different. Please only tag the relevant dbms.

Comment: use table aliases

Comment: Smaller? Like less letters to type, or less result set rows, or faster execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need all the parts of this query, so there's nothing that can just be dropped from the query.
You could, however, use table aliases to reduce the amount of text:

```
SELECT t.TempName, tsp.TimeSpan, tst.[Type], ts.Potition, ts.duuration
FROM TimeSpans tsp
INNER JOIN Templates t ON  t.TimeSpanId = tsp.Id
INNER JOIN TemplateSlots ts ON  t.Id = ts.TemplateId 
INNER JOIN TemplateSlotTypes tst ON  ts.[Type] = tst.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Table aliases will make the joins less verbose, but assuming the field names are unique to the tables involved you don't need to prefix them with the table name.

```
SELECT TempName
      ,TimeSpan
      ,[Type]
      ,Potition
      ,duration
FROM TimeSpans ts
INNER JOIN Templates t ON  t.TimeSpanId = ts.Id
INNER JOIN TemplateSlots s ON t.Id = s.TemplateId 
INNER JOIN TemplateSlotTypes st ON  s.[Type] = st.Id
```

However, I would recommend the use of a good IDE for SQL query development where it performs the joins for you and removes a lot of the typing.

Manually reducing the amount of text in a query is a false economy in the long run. It can actually make the SQL harder to read, and therefore more time consuming to modify or debug in the future.